# How to use complex nested queries in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, subquery, cypher, with-statement

I have a query in Cypher which finds the latest last time of a certain device. 
I want to match all the devices in my DB where their last time attribute is the lastest of their device and then return their id. unfortunately, I couldn't create a proper subquery.

I have tried using examples of with and {} but couldn't find anything that worked.

The main bulk (that works):

```
MATCH (a:device)
MATCH (b:device)
WHERE certain filters
RETURN
CASE 
WHEN a.last_seen > MAX(b.last_seen) THEN a.last_seen 
WHEN a.last_seen < MAX(b.last_seen) THEN MAX(b.last_seen)
ELSE a.last_seen END AS lastest
```

And then I want to do:

```
MATCH (d:device)
WHERE d.last_seen = lastest
RETURN d.device_id
```

Whatever I tried so far got me only syntax errors. How do I nest the bulk query?

Comment: What happens if `RETURN` is replaced with `WITH` in your "main bulk"?

Comment: Can you share how you are combining these two queries?

Comment: When I try to replace it with "with" I get a Syntax error, so I'm using it wrong. How should it be used? And Raj - that's what I want to know how to do :)

Comment: Please check my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest last_seen using **MAX function.**

Then you can use it to get all the devices with the **latest last_seen**.

Here is the query to get the max of last_seen and then get all the devices matching this last_seen.

```
MATCH (a:device)
WHERE certain filters
WITH MAX(a.last_seen) AS latest_last_seen
MATCH (d:device)
WHERE d.last_seen = latest_last_seen
RETURN d.device_id
```

(**Replace *certain filters* with the filters that you want to apply. I think you forgot to add certain filters in the second query**).

> **EDIT: As suggested by @InverseFalcon, Add an index on property last_seen**

Comment: For fast lookup in the last match, you'll also want to make sure you have an index on :device(last_seen)

Comment: This solution will work only for 1 device. I want to run this on my entire device DB. Max doesn't work in this case for the entirety of it :/

Comment: This will work for all the devices, Can you share what are you getting? What are you putting in "Certain Filters"?